# How to add a css class to jquery selectable

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-selectable

Using a jquery selectable in a project. The code for this looks like:

```
<li class="ui-widget-content">

.selectable li {
            margin: 1px;
            padding: 0.4em;
            height: 0.52em;
            line-height: 0.54em;
            position: relative;
            cursor: default;                               
        }
```

What i'm trying to do is add a margin-right to the li on some conditions dynamically

```
<li class="ui-widget-content groups">



.groups {
        padding-right: 10px;
    }
```

This to not work. If I add padding-right: 10px; in .selectable li, the padding is added. But like I said it doesn't work when adding the padding as an extra class and that's what I need to do in order to sometimes have padding and sometimes not depending on some condition.

When looking in the browsers inspector I can se that jquery has also added an extra class "ui-selectee":

```
<li class="ui-widget-content groups ui-selectee" >
```

Have also tried to add the extra class first like this:

```
<li class="groups ui-widget-content">
```

Witch renders

```
<li class="groups ui-widget-content ui-selectee" >
```

Also not working.

In the inspector the .groups class is not crossed over.

Does anybody know why adding the class does not add the padding?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess jquery selectable is overriding your style as .selectable li already contains a padding of 0.4em.
So try using this code :

```
.groups {
        padding-right: 10px !important;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Improve "value" of your class just adding additional class to your css rules. For example:

```
.ui-widget-content.groups{
    padding-right: 10px;
}
```

or

```
.ui-widget-content.ui-selectee.groups{
    padding-right: 10px;
}
```

Avoid to use `!important` in your CSS, because it may cause a lot of problems in the future. You can learn rules how to CSS specificity is calculated [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#specificity).